# Checking if an object is an instance of an Interface

Tags: c#, interface, unity-game-engine

I have a class called `MeleeWeapon` that inherits from the class `Item` and the interface `Usable`. I have an array of type Item which contains some objects which are type MeleeWeapon and I would like to know how to check if they are usable or not. I have tried the following methods but both result in false being logged. Any advice? 
(the item at this index is of type weapon, I have made sure of this)
I have searched for this answer, which is where I got these methods, so I apologize for the repeat, its just not working for me.

```
Debug.Log ( itemType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Usable))); 
Debug.Log (inv.items[inv.selectedHotbarSlot].item is Usable);
```

Comment: Clarify "not working for me". "is Usable" is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to get a bool value of true, but am getting false.

Comment: Then go and debug your code. You didn't provide an example sufficient to demonstrate the problem, so you can't expect any better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
if (obj.IsInstanceOfType(Usable))
```

Comment: Thats basically what I put as examples at the bottom of my post, except in an if statement instead of inside a log. I get false when it should be true.

Comment: @donsavage:- Can you try with:- if (obj.IsInstanceOfType(service))

Comment: @R.T. I could be mistaken but that doesn't compile in Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I check if an object is of a type.

```
public interface A 
{
}

public class B : MonoBehaviour, A 
{
    void Start () 
    {
        Debug.Log(this is A); // Will print True.
    }
}
```

Remember `this` in this case is the instance of the script `B`.

You can write it inside an `if`

```
if(obj is A)
// Do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `IsAssignableFrom` backwards (which is a fairly common error).

`IsAssignableFrom` would return true if the following would "work" (Assume `MyItemType` extends Usable):

```
Usable usable = new Usable(); //Pretend this constructor exists
MyItemType itemType = usable;
```

In other words it is checking if an object of the type `MyItemType` would be *assignable from* an object of the type `Usable`.

It seems what you want to test, is if this would work:

```
MyItemType itemType = new MyItemType();
Usable usable = itemType;
```

To do that switch the position of your types:

`Debug.Log(typeof(Usable).IsAssignableFrom(itemType));`